# Go through json array with PHP foreach

Tags: php, json

So i have a JSON like this

```
    {
        orderID: "8",
            .....
        OrderLines: {
            OrderLine: [
                {
                    orderLineID: "42",
                    quantity: "25",
                    price: "0.69",
                    originalPrice: "0.69",
                    checkedIn: "2",
                    numReceived: "0",
                    timeStamp: "2015-01-03T19:37:38+00:00",
                    orderID: "8",
                    itemID: "43944"
                },
                {
                    orderLineID: "44",
                    quantity: "75",
                    price: "0.69",
                    originalPrice: "0.69",
                    checkedIn: "25",
                    numReceived: "0",
                    timeStamp: "2015-01-07T20:07:29+00:00",
                    orderID: "8",
                    itemID: "43948"
                },
               ...
            ]
        }
    }
```

But when it's only one orderLine is looks like this

```
    {
        orderID: "20",
           ....
        OrderLines: {
            OrderLine: {
                orderLineID: "118",
                    quantity: "24",
                    price: "9",
                    originalPrice: "9",
                    checkedIn: "44",
                    numReceived: "0",
                    timeStamp: "2015-01-20T19:22:54+00:00",
                    orderID: "20",
                    itemID: "37826"
            }
        }
    }
```

When i do foreach in first case it gives me correct results (i'm getting needed data from each of orderlines), but when it's only 1 item in the order it goes through the array of that 1 orderline and gives me wrong data.

```
foreach ($orderLines['OrderLine'] as $orderLine) {
               echo $orderLine['quantity'];
               echo $orderLine['numReceived'];
}
```

How should i let it know that when it's only 1 order to give me just the right rows from this array ?

Comment: Where does the JSON come from? Can you edit that? I would think you'd rather keep the structure the same in the first place.

Comment: what is `wrong data` and `right rows`?

Comment: Have you looked at `json_decode()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: decode to native php array, then check if `$decoded['OrderLines']['OrderLine']` is an array or a stdclass object?

Comment: use php json_decode and json_encode functions

Comment: @mopo922 - it is an API and it's not editable

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're already using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert this JSON into a PHP array/object, you could check to see if OrderLine is an array, and only do the loop if that's the case:

```
if (is_array($orderLines['OrderLine']) {
    foreach ($orderLines['OrderLine'] as $orderLine) {
        echo $orderLine->quantity;
        echo $orderLine->numReceived;
    }
} else {
    echo $orderLines['OrderLine']->quantity;
    echo $orderLines['OrderLine']->numReceived;
}
```

Comment: It still returns true, since it is an array. In first case - it is an array of orderline arrays , in second - it's just an array of one orderline

Comment: @user3862703 Are you using `json_decode()`? If so, things enclosed by `[ ]` should be arrays and things enclosed by `{ }` should be stdClass objects.

Comment: or cast it to an array to avoid the `is_array` method.

Comment: @Ortix92 then you would just have to use a different method to determine if there was just one OrderLine or more.